# converting to system.net.mail.mailMessage error

Tags: c#

i'm actually trying to create registration page with verfication mail using MVC in visual studio,  but here to send a message im getting

> error :  'RandLform.Controllers.MailMessage' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage' RandLform

```cs
public void SendVerficationLinkEmail(string emailID, string activationCode)
{
    var VerifyUrl = "/User/VerifyAccount/" + activationCode;

    var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, VerifyUrl);

    var fromEmail = new MailAddress("lokeshkingdom4u@gmail.com", "Lokesh Pladugula");

    var toEmail = new MailAddress(emailID);

    var fromEmailPassword = "paisa007";

    string subject = "Account created Succesfully!";

    string body = "<br/>To verify your account, click on below link.<br/><br/> "+" <a href = "+link+"> "+link+"</a>";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NewNetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)

    };

    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    }) 
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Why did you create your own `MailMessage` class?

Answer (score 0):

Lokesh Paladugula,

I recommend you to change password of your email account.

I'm not sure if this is actual error, please send proper error.